# Can I save up spell learning "for later"?

Tags: dnd-5e, warlock, character-advancement

As a level 3 Warlock, I didn't learn any spell at level 2 (mainly because I just couldn't decide which one to pick, so the DM told me to tell him when I make up my mind about which spell I wanted to learn). Now at level 3 I wonder if I can use the "spell learning" from the previous level to learn 2 level 2 spells, instead of a level 1 and a level 2 spell.

Comment: We operate with one question per post. I've removed the second question — please *do* post it separately! It's not clutter, it's how anything can stay organised. :) Thanks!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

### Yes and No

In this case, "learning the spell" is retroactive to level 2. At level 2, Warlocks only have 1st level spell slots. According to the PHB:

> A spell you choose must be of a level no higher than what's shown in the table's Slot Level column for your level.

However, if you'd like to simply choose a 2nd level spell for the spell gained at level 2, there's a simple workaround (immediately following in the PHB):

> ...when you gain a level in this class, you can choose one of the warlock spells you know and replace it with another spell from the warlock spell list, which also must be of a level for which you have spell slots.

If you switch out the spell you hypothetically learned at level 2, you can have two 2nd level spells as a level 3 warlock. Whether you have to pick a 1st level spell to swap out for the 2nd level one is probably a question for your DM.

Comment: That's fantastic, I overlooked that part on the PHB. Thank you very much!